# Merge multiple spring-boot property file in a single file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-properties

Is there any automation tool that allows merging multiple properties files in a single file, using spring boot profiles:

from:

- application-dev.properties
- application-uat.properties
- application-prd.properties

to:

- application.properties

I know I could do this with a copy/paste but there are hundreds of files for different environments so I want to avoid mistakes.

Thanks

Comment: awk is powerful unix tool suited for this

Comment: Theses files are normal in Spring boot, why do you want to merge it? And also, there's probably no tools as it's not common to change Spring boot properties behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a shell script to do this while app deployment or right some task in grade/maven to merge all the files.

Or you can use @PropertySource to add all of these properties.